# CIS recommendations - disabling ip forwarding

Tags: linux, compliance, routing, configuration

I am looking through the [CIS recommendations](https://www.cisecurity.org/cis-benchmarks/) for debian 8.

In a CIS compliance test using nessus, I see that the test for disabling ip forwarding has failed. But when I look at the system, I can see that it is in fact disabled.

> ```
> $ cat /proc/net/ipv4/ip_forward
> 0
> ```

It seems like the CIS recommendation is to explicitly disable ip forwarding. But as far as I can tell, if you do not enable ip_forwarding explicitly, it will remain disabled.

Is there a bigger reason to do what the recommendation says, other than to make sure the default parameter is set?

For reference, I added the chapter for ip_forwarding below:

**7.1.1 Disable IP Forwarding (Scored)**

Profile Applicability:

Level 1

**Description:**
The net.ipv4.ip_forward flag is used to tell the server whether it can forward packets or
not. If the server is not to be used as a router, set the flag to 0.

**Rationale:**
Setting the flag to 0 ensures that a server with multiple interfaces (for example, a hard
proxy), will never be able to forward packets, and therefore, never serve as a router.

**Audit:**

Perform the following to determine if net.ipv4.ip_forward is enabled on the system.

> # /sbin/sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
>
> net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0

**Remediation:**

Set the net.ipv4.ip_forward parameter to 0 in /etc/sysctl.conf:

net.ipv4.ip_forward=0

Modify active kernel parameters to match:

> # /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
>
> # /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.route.flush=1

Comment: Looks like a false positive to me. I would ignore it. You could contact Nessus support to ask them to tweak the plugin.

Comment: Looks like the whole chapter 7 is false positives. The default values in debian 8 are in compliance with CIS

Comment: You don't want to rely on default values.  They change throughout distros/kernel versions.  Make it nice and explicit, and you will never have to wonder what it's set to.

Comment: i'm unable to disable ip_forward permanently on ubuntu. Maybe your issue is related to mine:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162147/ubuntu-18-04-disable-ip-forwarding-permanently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a bigger reason to do what the recommendation says, other
>   than to make sure the default parameter is set?

Similar to configuring firewall ACLs, the best practice is to explicitly configure the settings you want and not rely on the default (which may be different from device to device. For example, ACLs should end in *deny all and log*.

There are many reasons for being explicit in your configurations:

- Not all systems have the same *default* value
- Setting the desired value explicitly aids in accountability
- Audit Requirements